# How to make a tabbed window as in the picture using Visual C# (Studio 2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

[image: WIn32 Visual C# Application]

Being horrible at the design end, I tried creating the above code and it looked horrible. I still did not figure out how to create the tabbed look and move between screens.

Any leads or help with this would appreciated... I am not looking for the entire work, but just how do I create that white space when a tab is selected with the options in them.

Any other information required, I would be happy to reply.

Thank you

PS: The problem is solved...thank you

Comment: Did you Google it? http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=windows+forms+tab+control

Comment: Thank you, I got confused with the name. Was googling all the while for menu and tabbed menu and was not able to find relevant results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Tab Control of Windows Forms? Do you need to create it yourself?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4akwf92a.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the help. Much appreciated. I think I can use Tab Control. Is there a possibility of creating my own?

Comment: @VivianLobo: Of course there is the possibility to create your own Tab Control. What are you trying to achieve?